# Make a Call from Sleep

Tags: android, call, sleep, wakeup

I made an App which Monitors the Accelerometer of the Phone
and when it's tilted it should call a certain Number.

I got everythung running so far and it even does the call,
but only after I unlock the phone per Hand.

The App is meant to call me when someone tries to steal the tires from
my car, so the phone must call me from the sleep state.

Here is my call Method and relevant variables:

```
    PowerManager powerManager;
    WakeLock fullWakeLock; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        fullWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Loneworker - FULL WAKE LOCK");

    }
```

...

```
    public void call(){

    fullWakeLock.acquire();

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();

    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.nPhoneToCall)).getText().toString()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("", "Call failed", e);
    }
}
```

Edit: Oh I also tried:

```
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Like I said he does make the call
but only if the screen is already unlocked :(

edit2:
Must run on Android 2.1 ( API Level 7 )

Please help :3

Comment: You should be a DeviceAdministrator to be able to unlock the phone.

Comment: Hello,
I looked for it and the internet says Device Administration was introduced with 2.2, ist there a way around it for 2.1?

Comment: Store the phone number in e.g. `SharedPreferences` and use a `Service`. Calling numbers automatically might require a rooted phone though

Comment: I don't believe there's any mechanism to monitor the accelerometer while the phone is in powered-down sleep. But if building custom hardware, there are accelerometer chips with micropower mode alarm thresholds that can signal a wakeup interrupt to a connected application processor.

Comment: The accelerometer is read out correctly.
I hooked it up over night to check and the next day
everything was recorded as it should be.

My problen is really just the call :(

Comment: @Splitframe if it's for 2.1 then the keyguard unlock should have worked, it doesn't work on new versions because of DeviceAdministrator

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you are looking for but you could just leave the phone on the car charger (and hide it).

Android devices hava an option to stay awake (and unlocked) while charging. Check the developer options on your device.

Comment: Sadly the phone doesn't seem to have that feature, it's
a Xperia x8 with 2.1-updt1. I also can't disable the slide to
unlock.